# Internal Server Error Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, internal-server-error

Since a few days, I have a problem with my website.
When I go to the URL : [striptekening.com](http://www.striptekening.com), a 500 Internal Server Error will return. I don't know why. Nothing is changed.

The website is build in Drupal 7

My phpinfo file can be found here : [phpinfo file](http://www.striptekening.com/info.php)

Server errorlog:

[Tue Oct 30 10:58:10 2012] [warn] [client 193.239.187.26] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 31 seconds

[Tue Oct 30 10:58:10 2012] [error] [client 193.239.187.26] Premature end of script headers: index.php

I Hope that you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off fast CGI and try! Some things fast CGI may not support.